# C# Executing Command in CMD working on localhost but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cmd, gltf

I am trying to execute a *gltf-pipeline* command from an **asp .net mvc4** application.

```
private string InitializeCmdProcess(string pathOfFile, string pathOfFileOutput)
        {
            string command2 = "gltf-pipeline -i \"" + pathOfFile + "\" -o \"" + pathOfFileOutput + "\" -d";
            string command = "/K \"" + command2 + "\"";
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
            {
                Arguments = command,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            };

            var process = Process.Start(psi);
            return command2;
        }
```

The above code is working on localhost, the command outputs a file fine and everything works fine.

But when I try it on a windows server it doesn't work.

When I click a button I send an ajax request to trigger the above code, the website freezes and the request takes too long. When the request is finished (after sometime) it gives a 200 successful response but the command doesn't output a file in the  *pathOfFileOutput*.

The command itself is working since when I open the cmd on the remote server and execute the same command it works.

Comment: I wonder why it even works locally: Within the `/K "..."` you have to double any additional quote characters.

Comment: Why starting `cmd` to start something else, why not simply start `gltf-pipeline` immediately?

Comment: When you open it, it's you. When the web request runs it, it runs as that user, whatever it was configured to be. That is, the site runs as a user and that is the user trying to execute the command. Does that user have permissions to run this?

Comment: @KlausGütter it wouldn't work without it, I read somewhere that the /K is to tell the cmd that there is a command after it.

Comment: @aschipfl how do I do that? It's a command that runs on the cmd. If there is a way to execute the command without opening the cmd please tell me.

Comment: @Nikki9696 Could be, since I am executing the command from the app. Is there a way to give all privileges to the process? I am logging in as an admin and the command works fine.